# How to do error handling in Express and NodeJS for Mongoose Error.

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, mongoose

I have a NodeJS Application with Express as my web server and Mongoose as my abstraction layer over MongoDB.Now a simple Express route is written like this.

```
module.exports.getProfile = function(req, res, next) {
    Users.findOne({
        '_id': req.user._id
    }).exec(function(err, profile) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } else if (profile) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                'profile': profile
            }));
        } else {
            res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': "Profile Not found"
            }));
        }
    });
};
```

Now I have at least 100 function like these in my app and instead of writing res.sendStatus(500) every time, I want to create one function like this.

```
var sendError = function(err, res, next) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': "Internal server error. Couldn't connect to database. Please report this issue and try again"
        }));
        next();
    }
};
```

And for every DB call. if(err) sendError(err, res, next); Doesn't work and somehow I feel it's not right. So what is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Express.errorHandler` for this purpose. It described in  [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: Express.errorHandler is that a express function because it's not given in the link of documentation page you gave above.

Comment: It's documentation about error handling workflow in Express.
Function with 4 parameters calling error handler and if you call next() in your route and pass `err` to it than execution flow will be given to this function.

Comment: Okay so do you mean to say if I give next(err); in the above function instead of res.sendStatus(500);  and write a function `app.use(function(err, req, res, next){ res.status(500).send('Something broke!');})` It will work?

Comment: Yes. Also you must to be sure that you add error handler after you add your route function like this:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Tdry2mxY)